# troubleshooting celery and redis for Django app

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I need help troubleshooting `celery` run with `redis` for a Django app. In this app, users upload photos, and I'm trying to run a background process that will periodically rank all photos according to user votes and time passed since uploading (think of it like a basic reddit-like ranking algorithm).

I have `celery.py` in my project folder (same folder as `settings.py`), containing:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

app = Celery('myapp', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0',include=['myfolder.myapp.tasks'])
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS) 

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

`tasks.py` mentioned in the file above, is situated in the `myapp` folder, and contains:

```
import os
from myproject import celery_app1
import time
from myapp.models import Photo

@celery_app1.task(name='tasks.rank_all_photos')
def rank_all_photos():
    for photo in Photo.objects.all():
        photo.set_rank()
        print "ranked"
```

`__init__.py` in the myproject folder contains:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app1
```

Lastly, relevant config from `settings.py` is as follows:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

CELERY_IMPORTS = ('myapp.tasks', )  

CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=True

from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'tasks.rank_all_photos': {
        'task': 'tasks.rank_all_photos',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),
    },
}

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

Note that `'djcelery'` is also included in INSTALLED_APPS. To me, all of the above looks about right. When I run `celery worker -A myproject --loglevel=INFO`, I see the output:

```
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.16.0-30-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         myapp:0x7f0a15acb310
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . tasks.rank_all_photos

[2016-05-17 02:19:19,733: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2016-05-17 02:19:19,745: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-05-17 02:19:20,750: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:265: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2016-05-17 02:19:20,761: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/hassan/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:265: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2016-05-17 02:19:20,761: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@hassan ready.
```

I see that output, yet I don't see any evidence that `tasks.py` was processed. No output is printed, nor is any ranking done.

I'm a beginner, so am probably missing something fundamental here. Can you please have a look and troubleshoot this for me? I'm currently only trying to test this in the fg locally - once it's up and running, I'll look into daemonizing it in production. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to run celery beat.

```
celery beat -A myproject --loglevel=INFO
```